# Scala. Append to Map's value, which is ListBuffer

Tags: scala, data-structures, append, key

I have an empty Map with empty ListBuffer as a default value.

```
val map: Map[String, ListBuffer[String]] = Map.empty.withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
```

When I address to it's yet not existing keys and want to append some values, it does something unexpected:

```
// map += "one" -> ListBuffer("l")
map("one") += "lo"
map("two") += "lol"
map("one") += "la"

println(map("one").result)
```

I thought it should print `List(lo, la)`, but it prints `List(lo, lol, la)`.
`for(m <- map) println(m)` doesnt print anything.
If I uncomment `map += "one" -> ListBuffer("t")` it prints `List(l, lo, la)` which is correct, but `println("two(or any other key)")` prints `List(lo, lol, la)`.
How can I fix that? Is something there what I don't know about?

Comment: @RamanMishra oh... how to mutate the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because your map has default value - `ListBuffer()`
when you try to add something to map:
`map("one") += "lo"`
actually map looked for key `one` found nothing and get default value - `ListBuffer()`. After, `lo` appended to `ListBuffer()` and default value now is `ListBuffer("lo")`.
Same algo repeated for `two` and `one` keys. In this way, key `one` (and rest keys also) will never being put to the map.

Also you are using immutable map, and it creates new map after adding. If you want to collect map with all keys and values, you can use foldLeft:

```
val map: Map[String, ListBuffer[String]] = Map.empty.withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
val newMap = Seq(
  "one" -> "lo",
  "two" -> "lol",
  "one" -> "la"
).foldLeft(map){
  case (accMap, (key, value)) => accMap + (key -> (value +: accMap(key)))
}
println(newMap("one").result) // List(la, lo)
println(newMap) // Map(one -> ListBuffer(la, lo), two -> ListBuffer(lol))
```

or you can use muatable map:

```
val map: mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[String]] = mutable.Map.empty.withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
map.update("one",  "lo" +: map("one"))
map.update("two",  "lol" +: map("two"))
map.update("one",  "la" +: map("one"))
println(map("one").result) // List(la, lo)
println(map) // Map(one -> ListBuffer(la, lo), two -> ListBuffer(lol))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have sequence of tuples like this

`val keyValue = Seq(
    "one" -> "lo",
    "two" -> "lol",
    "one" -> "la"
  )`

i would suggest you to use `groupBy` like this

```
println(x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)))
```

As it's not good to use mutable Data structures in Scala, you might to think about the design and try to change it.

why you are not getting the desired output from your code is because you have an immutable Map if you want to update the map you need to have a mutable map which provides you the method update, here you are taking `map("one") += "la"` here what is happening you are getting listBuffer when you do map("one") which is empty then you are updating that listBuffer with `"lo"` using `+=` and same for the `"two" and "one"` But if you will see your map is still empty there is nothing in the map because you didn't updated the map you have updated the listBuffer. Which you get from `map("one")` which is an empty listBuffer.

you will get the same result if you will use anystring in the print like

```
println(map("").result) //List("lo", "lol", "la")
```